# Why is pseudo-Bayesian Model Averaging using WAIC giving counterintuitive results for my model? Issue with unconstrained data uncertainty?

Tags: regression, bayesian, model-comparison, model-averaging

I'm currently working on a model which fits a pair of curves which are parameterized by some shape and scaling parameters. I want to produce weights for two different models. In my first model, which we can call 'Model 0', both curves have the same shape parameters, curve b is equal to (1 - curve a) multiplied by a scaling parameter. In 'Model 1', curve b and curve a may have different shape parameters. In other words, 'Model 1' is more complex, but should provide better fits to the data.

In the following figure, I give an example of a fit to data where Model 1 clearly appears to be more appropriate. The top two figures show the curves fit, and the bottom two figures plot the y values of each curve against one another, which will always be linear under Model 0.

[image]

However, if I calculate the WAIC for each of these models using pseudo-BMA, I obtain ~ -238 for Model 0 and ~ -220 for Model 1 which would indicate that Model 0 is preferred with near certainty. I suspect the issue here is that the standard deviation of the uncertainty on the data points, which I gave an exponential prior, is estimated to be about 50% larger for Model 0 than Model 1. This leads to very similar lppds for both models.

In another example (figure below), a counterintuitive result again happens. In this case, the fits for Model 0 and Model 1 are rather similar, although Model 1 still provides a slightly better fit than expected.

[image]

In this case, the standard deviation of the uncertainty of the data differs less than in the first example, and so the the lppd for Model 1 is significantly better. Strangely, the $p_{WAIC \ 2}$ term between the models for this set of data is very similar, and so Model 1 ends up being heavily favored over Model 0. We end up with a WAIC of ~ -235 for Model 0 vs ~ -250 for Model 1.

Unless I am making some error in calculation (I am using the formulae from Gelman (2014)), these WAIC values seem to be counterintuitive. I can only think that the unconstrained uncertainty value is what is causing this problem due to the lack of prior information in the WAIC calculation, but perhaps there is something else I am missing.

Is there another approach that I could take to model averaging? I'm not certain LOO-CV will work as this also uses the likelihood averaged over the posterior.